# Gradle settings error

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle. Please use version 1.10. 
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.) 
Gradle settings

how to resolve above qouery ?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of a question raised at Gradle forum - http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_settings_error

It is not a query but an error statement and it tells you what to do.

Comment: That i know, I tried to fix that error,but it's not happening.Can u help me out ?